# Trying to do a wrap around for an image navigator in JQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, navigation

I am making a simple image navigator using JQuery.

So, for example, if we have 3 images in total, it will look something like this:

```
Prev 1 2 3 Next
```

I am using the `.hide()` function with `.click()` to implement this.

So every time I click on one navigation option, one image is shown, while the rest are hidden.

I got the "1 2 3" links to work.

I am having problems with the "Prev" and "Next" though.

I have to do a wrap-around for them. So If I am on "1" and I press "Prev", I have to go to "3". Or if I am on "3" and I press "Next", I go to "1".

I wrote the click functions for "Prev" and "Next" like this:

```
//Write the onClick() event handler for "Prev"
    $('#prev').click(function(){

        ind = ($('.image').index('.image:visible')+1);

        if (ind == 1){
            hideAll(totalImages);
        }
        else{
            hideAll(ind-1);
        }
    });

    //Write the onClick() event hadler for "Next"
    $('#next').click(function(){
        ind = ($('.image').index('.image:visible')+1;

        if (ind == totalImages){
            hideAll(1);
        }
        else{
            hideAll(ind+1);
        }
    });
```

Note that `hideAll(index)` is a function which hides all the images except the one specified by "index".

**It does not work properly in the following way:**

From 1, if I press "Prev", I properly end up at 3.
But when I press "Prev" again, all the images go blank. The value of "ind" goes to ZERO.

From 1, if I press "Next", I properly end up at 2.
But from 2, if I press "Next", I end up at 1 again, rather than going to 3.

Comment: So what does "it doesn't work" mean? Does it not switch at all? Does it switch to the wrong image? Have you used `console.log` to output the index that you're trying to switch to when you click the Next and Prev links?

Comment: It stops all of the rest of my code from executing. So I don't have a navbar, or anything. None of the other divs I added dynamically, they don't get added.

Comment: Do you get javascript errors of any sort? Usually when other scripts stop working, it's because a javascript exception occurred and that's stop all further processing.

Comment: I'm so sorry, yes there was a Javascript error, silly bracket thing. 

Ok, now the rest of my code is working, but there is some logical error.

I edited the question above to describe the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to to check which image is the first/last in index. This is not the complete solution for your problem but should you give an idea how you can fix it.

Take a look at the `previous()` and `next()` function.

```
// Cache jQuery results
var element = $(this);
var items = element.find(options.slideitem);

// How many items to slide?
var total = items.length;
var count = 0;

// Hide all items but not first item
items.not(':first').hide();

// Calculate next item
function next() {      
    (count == total - 1) ? count = 0 : count++;
    transition(items, count);
    return false
};

// Calculate previous item
function previous() {
    (count == 0) ? count = total - 1 : count--;
    transition(items, count);
    return false
};

// Do transition between two slides
function transition(items, count) {
    if (options.effect == 'show') {
        items.hide().eq(count).show();
    };
    if (options.effect == 'fadeIn') {
        items.css('position', 'absolute');
        items.fadeOut(options.fadespeed).eq(count).fadeIn(options.fadespeed);
    };
};
```